# Linking two dropdown lists together not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where there are two dropdown lists that are populated from the same dataset, so their values should be equal.  I have the OnSelectedIndexChanged event in code and the AutoPostBack set to true for the second drop down.  The behavior expected is that when a user selects an item from the second dropdown, the first should change to what was selected in the second.  My code in the event looks like this:

```
if(!ddl1.SelectedValue.Equals(ddl2.SelectedValue)
{
    ddl1.SelectedValue = ddl2.SelectedValue;
}
```

The OnSelectedIndexChanged event also contains code that rebinds the datagrid on the bottom of the page based on the selection of the second dropdownlist.  Long story short, the datagrid changes, but the first dropdown does not change its value.  It doesn't seem like a postback should limit what would change on a page, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!ddl1.SelectedValue.Equals(ddl2.SelectedValue)
{
     ddl1.ClearSelection();
     ddl1.Items.FindByValue(ddl2.SelectedValue).Selected = True
}
```

Comment: Tried this one.  Got an error on page stating that multiple values cannot be selected at the same time.  Tried de-selecting the current value, then it went back to the normal 'not changing its value' behavior.

Comment: `ddl1.ClearSelection();`   before doing selection

Comment: This works, thanks!  Guess I forgot about the .ClearSelection() method; I was going about it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    if (!ddl1.SelectedIndex == ddl2.SelectedIndex)
{
ddl1.SelectedIndex == ddl2.SelectedIndex
}
```